# Angularjs expression behavior

Tags: angularjs, expression

Why? html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <div data-ng-show="{{tags.length > 2}}"><p>{{tags}}</p></div>
        <p>{{tags.length > 2}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.tags = 'Go go go';
    });
```

And shows only 'true'... Why div is hidden?

http://jsfiddle.net/3HT2F/11/

Comment: remove them curly braces. This is an expression, not a binding

Also, have a look at the API: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user2422960 says, you just need to remove the `{{` and `}}` because `ng-show` already expects an expression:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <div data-ng-show="tags.length > 2"><p>{{tags}}</p></div>
        <p>{{tags.length > 2}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davintryon/caVaQ/).